# Confirm all columns in a pandas dataframe are 1-D

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

It is not good practise to include multi-arrays/lists as columns in a pandas dataframe. In the event that I want to raise a value error whenever any column in a dataframe is not 1-D.

Given a dataset

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(
        [
            [1, (0,2), 0, 3], 
            [1, (0,0), 1, 2], 
            [0, (5,1),6, 1], 
            [4, (3,0), 3, 4],
            [1, (1,1), 0, 2],
            [2, (0,1), 3, 5],
            [1, (3,3), 1, 2],
            [6, (4,3), 5, 3],
            [3, (0,2), 1, 2],
            [2, (0,0), 2, 1],
        ]
    ),
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

I want to do something similar to

```
if columns in dfA are not all 1-D:
    raise ValueError("Dataframe must only have 1-D columns")
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `1-D` here? I see all `1-D` columns only in your df.

Comment: I assume you mean not a simple _scalar_ value (string, int, bool, float, etc.), since you can have a 1D np.array, which I would _think_ you also mean to flag? The trickiest part of this could depend on how clean your data are before this step -- in your example `df` has all `object` columns, when 3 of them likely _should_ be stored as a numeric dtype. And do you expect the same type of object to be stored in all rows? `object` columns could have any mixture of objects anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can slice the 1st row , then `np.shape`

```
dfA.iloc[0].map(lambda x :np.shape(x))!=()
Out[413]: 
A    False
B     True
C    False
D    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```